# Fast indexing / value setting in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, oop, object, speech

I'm writing a python package to decompose a speech signal into its spectral harmonics, so that each one of them could be represented as a complex exponential. A (very) simplified description of the code is presented below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

class HarmObj(object):

    # Creates an instance for each harmonic.
    def __init__(self, file_size):
        self.mag = np.zeros((file_size))
        self.phi = np.zeros((file_size))
        self.freq = np.zeros((file_size))

class SignalObj(object):

# Creates an instance for the synthesized speech signal, which is formed by the
# harmonics.
    def __init__(self, n_harm, file_size):
        self.n_harm = n_harm
        self.size = file_size
        self.harmonics = [HarmObj(self.size) for i in xrange(self.n_harm)]

    def update_values(self, a, freq, frame):
        for harmonic in xrange(self.n_harm):
            self.harmonics[harmonic].mag[frame] = np.abs(a[harmonic])
            self.harmonics[harmonic].phi[frame] = np.angle(a[harmonic])
            self.harmonics[harmonic].freq[frame] = freq[harmonic]

n_harm = 25
file_size = 100

signal = SignalObj(n_harm, file_size)

for frame in xrange(file_size):

    #Nevermind this part, is just a simplification ;)
    #----------------------------------------------
    real_part = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.9, n_harm)
    imag_part = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.9, n_harm)
    a = real_part + 1j*imag_part
    freq = np.random.normal(500.0, 200.0, n_harm)
    #-----------------------------------------------

    signal.update_values(a, freq, frame)
```

This script runs without a problem. However, since that in a speech signal the number of harmonics and frames can be big, the code would be somewhat computationally burdensome, due the `for` loop inside the `SignalObj.update_values` method.

I believe that a "numpy-array" solution like

```
    def update_values(self, a, freq, frame):
        self.harmonics[:].mag[frame] = np.abs(a[:])
        self.harmonics[:].phi[frame] = np.angle(a[:])
        self.harmonics[:].freq[frame] = freq[:]
```

would be faster. But the code above doesn't work with a list of objects. **So, I wonder if there is a way to either change the list properties OR create my own structure, allowing then the aforementioned optimized value setting process.**

PS. : By the way, one possible solution to evade this problem is to discard the `HarmObj` class and associate the `mag`, `phi` and `freq` attributes directly to the `SignalObj`, i.e.,

```
class SignalObj(object):

    def __init__(self, n_harm, file_size):
        self.n_harm = n_harm
        self.size = file_size
        self.mag = np.zeros((n_harm, file_size))
        self.phi = np.zeros((n_harm, file_size))
        self.freq = np.zeros((n_harm, file_size))

    def update_values(self, a, freq, frame):
        self.mag[:, frame] = np.abs(a[:])
        self.phi[:, frame] = np.angle(a[:])
        self.freq[:, frame] = freq[:]
```

I employed this workaround in the MATLAB version and it is indeed faster. However, since Python is more resourceful, I wonder if there is a more elegant and pythonic way to do the job ;). Moreover, keeping the `HarmObj` instances separated would help me later when I start manipulating them.

Comment: Is ```HarmObj``` *just* a container for three numpy arrays - no other attributes?

Comment: I want to add a method to the class, which will take the three numpy arrays and generate the synthesized individual harmonic. Then the `SignalObj` will sum all those harmonics and generate the synthesized signal.

Comment: Actually, to generate the harmonic signal I only need the magnitude and phase. But the frequency signal is necessary to refine the results from the extraction algorithm. This process helps to improve the quality of the final synthesized signal.

Comment: I'm no expert but I don't think you can't get `numpy` performance when using custom data types.  Your going to have to determine if the `HarmObj` encapsulation is worth the performance cost.  If the synthesis/extraction could be written as a *standalone* function and *vectorized* then your workaround might be the right direction - it seems that eventually your going to have to iterate over the `HarmObj`'s too. `SignalObj.harmonics` (H) could be represented by a (n_harm, 3, file_size) ndarray. Each harmonic would be H[n, :, :] and each frame would be H[:, :, n]

Comment: Yeah, probably it's better to keep the H ndarray as you advised and take advantage from `numpy` performance. To be honest, I don't mind using directly the H ndarray in the whole synthesis/extraction process. As I mentioned, that's the way I did while prototyping with MATLAB. But since that I want to share the code later with some researchers, I thought that eventually they (and maybe I as well) would like to manipulate the data from `HarmObj` in future works. So I was trying to make its access more "user-friendly".

Comment: Anyway, with this in mind, I came up with another workaround today. Besides directly using the H ndarray, a second option would be to design a wrapper (with `__getitem__` and `__getattribute__` I guess) so that the user could manipulate/index the harmonics parts in the way I presented above in my question. Then the command would be translated to the `numpy` array H. By now I'm working on this, let's see if I can get a solution.

Comment: ```SignalObject``` could easily have attributes that expose *views* of the harmonics in almost any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This code has some errors due to the method you are using to create `self.harmonics`

here is a simple demonstration of why that is problematic

```
class Foo()
    __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

foo = Foo('foo')
bar = [foo] * 3
for i in bar:
    print i.foo
```

this returns.

```
foo
foo
foo
```

looks fine...except its not, because they are all pointing to the same `foo` object. So

```
bar[0].foo = 'bar'
for i in bar:
    print i.foo
```

This returns:

```
bar
bar 
bar
```

Use list comprehension instead.

```
bar = [Foo('foo') for i in range(3)]
for i in bar:
   print i.foo
bar[0].foo = 'bar'
for i in bar:
   print i.foo
```

This gives the desired

```
foo
foo
foo
bar
foo
foo
```

for fast operations over lists you can also you list comprehension.

```
def update_harmonic(harmonic):
    real_part = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.9, n_harm)
    imag_part = np.random.normal(0.0, 0.9, n_harm)
    a = real_part + 1j*imag_part
    freq = np.random.normal(500.0, 200.0, n_harm)
    signal.update_values(a, freq, frame)

self.harmonics = [x.update_harmonic() for x in self.harmonics]
```

Comment: Oops, indeed, I've created the list in a wrong way, already corrected up there. Actually in my original code I've started it with a `for` loop. But as I copied it and edited it here, I ended up changing it.

Comment: I've also replaced the `for` loop by the list comprehension, and worked =). I've tried to implement it before posting the question here, but my version was raising an error.